chrome web driver not working in docker container
We use python -selenium for our web automation.
Untill few days the code was working perfectly fine few days ago on the server .
All of sudden after a new build things started to fail.
also tried a simple code .Which i tried to run in a docker container locally .
The problem is same its stuck at driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) but works locally on system
attaching Docker file and Py file .
Note: Tried with latest version as well
Docker file
FROM python:3.10-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install wget gnupg -y wget gnupg unzip curl xvfb



# Download and install Google Chrome
ENV CHROME_VERSION=120.0.6099.129-1
RUN wget -q https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_${CHROME_VERSION}_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y ./google-chrome-stable_${CHROME_VERSION}_amd64.deb

# Install ChromeDriver
RUN set -eux; \
    CHROME_VERSION=$(google-chrome --version | grep -oP '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+'); \
    echo "Installed Chrome version: $CHROME_VERSION"; \
    CHROME_MAJOR_VERSION=$(echo $CHROME_VERSION | cut -d '.' -f 1); \
    CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=$(curl -s "https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/LATEST_RELEASE_$CHROME_MAJOR_VERSION"); \
    echo "Installing ChromeDriver version: $CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION"; \
    wget -q "https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/${CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION}/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip"; \
    unzip chromedriver-linux64.zip -d /usr/local/bin/; \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver; \
    rm chromedriver-linux64.zip
# set display port to avoid crash
ENV DISPLAY=:99

# install selenium
RUN pip install selenium==4.15.0




# Create directories
RUN mkdir -p /src /src/Reports
COPY .env ./
COPY .env /src/


# Copy application source code
COPY src/utilites/ec_dashboard /src/utilites/ec_dashboard

# Set working directory and run the application
WORKDIR /src/
CMD ["python3", "utilites/ec_dashboard/dockertrial.py"]


Simple code file
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
# Set up the Selenium WebDriver
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor')
options.add_argument('--user-agent={}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)

# Open the Google website
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

# Print the title of the page
print(driver.title)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()


Tried all the possible versions also tried with fire fox .
Locally there is no issue
(venv) ➜  data-automation-testing git:(release/crontrial) ✗ docker run -it testauto2
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/src/utilites/ec_dashboard/dockertrial.py", line 15, in 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in init
super().init(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 56, in init
super().init(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 207, in init
self.start_session(capabilities)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 291, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 346, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
Stacktrace:
#0 0x555555cfbf83 
